# checkboxes with jquery validity

Tags: jquery, forms, checkbox, radio-button

There seems to be a problem in FF when you use jquery.validty.js to validate my forms. If I'm validating a checkbox or radio btn the X image doesn't show up. It works in safari but I haven't tried IE. Has anyone had this problem?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="Stylesheet" href="css/jquery.validity.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/validate/jquery.validity.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() { 
            $("form").validity(function() {
                $("#vehicles")
                    .require()
                    .match("number")
                    .range(4, 12);
                                    $("#butn").require();

                $("#dob")
                    .require()
                    .match("date")
                    .lessThanOrEqualTo(new Date());
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="get" action="simple.htm">
        Number of Vehicles:
        <input type="text" id="vehicles" name="vehicles" title="Vehicle Count" />
        <br /><br />
        Date of birth:
        <input type="text" id="dob" name="dob" title="Birthday" />
        <br /><br />
        <input type="radio" id="butn"/>
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: If it doesn't work in FF... most likely it won't work in IE. That being said, I have no idea what you're talking about... post some code, provide a link, let us help you.

Comment: Here is a basic set up of what I'm talking about. the check box won't validate.

Comment: I don't see a check box. I see two text fields and a radio button.

Comment: well true but it's the same issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

So here the jist of it. You have to add your own functions to handle it.

```
$("#terms").assert($("#terms:checked").length != 0,'');

<input id='terms' type='radio' />
```

Comment: You could consider your selection a "truthy" expression and simplify your assert to $("#terms").assert($("#terms:checked"),'');